# fluentd with OpenSearch - where does the @timestamp field come from?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, opensearch

I am running fluentd as a DaemonSet in a Kubernetes cluster. fluentd writes the log entries to OpenSearch. Take a look at https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset

I must lay some background before my question: The way it works is that Kubernetes pods write to stdout, and the container runtime writes this to a certain location, namely `/var/logs/pods/<pod_specific_location>` . The format of these log files is as such:

```
31-12-23T12:00:00.123456Z    stdout    F     my great log message
```

Now, fluentd is configured to pick it from there, and using the [cri parser plugin](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-parser-cri) transforms it to:

```
{
"time": "31-12-23T12:00:00.123456Z",
"stream": "stdout",
"logtag": "F",
"message": "my great log message"
}
```

Now, say I run a pod in my cluster that writes the following log message:

```
hello
```

Further down the road, using the [kubernetes metadata plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter), fluentd enriches this record with kubernetes metadata, such as namespace name, pod name, etc. etc., so it'll look something like:

```
{
"stream":"stdout",
"logtag":"F",
"time":"31-12-23T12:00:00.123456Z",
"message": "my great log message"
"docker":
{"container_id":"9077644273956d3f3e9d171240f412b3b6e959984a5fd99adfcb77f9b998a370"},
"kubernetes":
{"container_name":"demo-app",
"namespace_name":"foo",
"pod_name":"foo-ns-app",
"container_image":"docker.io/yoavklein3/net-tools:latest",
"container_image_id":"docker.io/yoavklein3/net-tools@sha256:3fd9646a14d97ecc2d236a5bebd88faf617bc6045f1e4f32c49409f1c930879a",
"pod_id":"a69fb942-c0ab-457d-b752-ffa3fa27e574",
"pod_ip":"10.0.2.224",
"host":"ip-10-0-2-5.ec2.internal",
"master_url":"https://172.20.0.1:443/api",
"namespace_id":"6bdf5fe9-9a5a-4501-ab6c-deddd241e071",
"namespace_labels":{"kubernetes.io/metadata.name":"foo"}}}
```

Now, using the [opensearch plugin](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-opensearch) it is sent to Opensearch.

Now, when I open Opensearch Dashboards, I can see a field called `@timestamp`, and I just can't figure out where this field comes from:

This is a document in OpenSearch (apologies for not sticking to the example above exactly, but the concept remains the same):

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2023.06.06",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "sVHjj4gByMQm1Wc45hv2",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "stream": "stdout",
    "logtag": "F",
    "time": "2023-06-06T08:47:35.874884092Z",
    "docker": {
      "container_id": "9077644273956d3f3e9d171240f412b3b6e959984a5fd99adfcb77f9b998a370"
    },
    "kubernetes": {
      "container_name": "demo-app",
      "namespace_name": "foo",
      "pod_name": "foo-ns-app",
      "container_image": "docker.io/yoavklein3/net-tools:latest",
      "container_image_id": "docker.io/yoavklein3/net-tools@sha256:3fd9646a14d97ecc2d236a5bebd88faf617bc6045f1e4f32c49409f1c930879a",
      "pod_id": "a69fb942-c0ab-457d-b752-ffa3fa27e574",
      "pod_ip": "10.0.2.224",
      "host": "ip-10-0-2-5.ec2.internal",
      "master_url": "https://172.20.0.1:443/api",
      "namespace_id": "6bdf5fe9-9a5a-4501-ab6c-deddd241e071",
      "namespace_labels": {
        "kubernetes.io/metadata.name": "foo"
      }
    },
    "data": "This is from FOO namespace",
    "@timestamp": "2023-06-06T08:47:35.882677347+00:00",
    "tag": "kubernetes.var.log.containers.foo-ns-app_foo_demo-app-9077644273956d3f3e9d171240f412b3b6e959984a5fd99adfcb77f9b998a370.log"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2023-06-06T08:47:35.882Z"
    ],
    "time": [
      "2023-06-06T08:47:35.874Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1686041255882
  ]
}
```

NOTE: the `message` field is missing, and there's the `data` field instead. This is due to parsing the `message` field as JSON. You can ignore this, it's completely irrelevant, just noting if you're confused.

### EDIT

I don't think that the source of this `@timestamp` field is the Opensearch plugin. Why? because when I run fluentd with opensearch NOT in a kubernetes cluster, but rather using other input plugins, I can't see this field.

Answer (score 0):

> I can see a field called @timestamp, and I just can't figure out where this field comes from...

This field is added by the opensearch [plugin](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-opensearch#include_timestamp), the value is the point in time when the message is ingested.

Comment: I don't think it is. see the edit

Comment: That's because your `logstash_format` is `false`, which is the default value.